# how to write a more Pythonic python code to convert a integer to a Iteration list?

Tags: python

we have a function can permit user input a integer/a string format/list format

```
   def testsum(data):
        if(type(data)==type(1)):
            data=map(int,str(data))

        for i in map(int,data):
            #print(type(i))
            print(i,i+20)

    if __name__=="__main__":
        testsum(1)#OK
        testsum([2,3,4])#OK
        testsum("123")#FAILS,we hope to be 143
        testsum(['5','6'])#OK
```

Comment: What is this function even supposed to do?

Comment: I don't understand *testsum("123")#FAILS,we hope to be 143*

Comment: It is an IQ test? If not then more Pythonic is: 17) "If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea." 18) "If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea." (Zen of Python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like:

```
def testsum(data):
    if not isinstance(data, list):
        data = [data]

    for i in map(int,data):
        print(i,i+20)
```

Note that it' usually not a good idea to design your functions like this. Better write two different functions, one for lists (iterables) and one for strings.

Comment: ohh 143 was a typo this makes sense

Comment: You get exception on "1a3"

Comment: That isn't in the domain of the function

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic way is always as close as possible to one line.

```
testsum = lambda data: data if isinstance(data,int) else sum([v*10**(len(data)-i) for i,v in enumerate(map(int,data),1)])

print(testsum(1))
print(testsum([2,3,4]))
print(testsum("123"))
print(testsum(['5','6']))
```

Or un-one-lined:

```
def testsum(data):
    if isinstance(data,int):
        return data
    else:
        return sum([v*10**(len(data)-i) for i,v in enumerate(map(int,data),1)])
```

Outputs:

> > > ```
> > > 1
> > > 234
> > > 123
> > > 56
> > > ```

Comment: Is that a joke? Complicated one-liners are positively anti-Pythonic.

Comment: Somewhat, I would agree that this one-liner loses the readability which comes with a one line statement due to its length/complexity, however I find terse one-lines much easier to understand than the equivalent 5-8 line long equivalent.

Comment: You can definitely go too far the other way, your un-one-lined example above is spot on for readability imo.